# Bulk NSArray write to SQLite

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I'm trying to bulk write an Array of Dictionaries into an SQLite db using a SQLite Transaction for speed as the Array can become quite large.

The code:

```
-(void)bulkCachetoSQLite:(NSArray *)dataToCache
{
    //Logging Comment
    NSLog(@"SQLiteClass - bulkCachetoSQLite");

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    const char *dbpath = [_filePath UTF8String];
    char * sErrMsg = 0;
    const char *tail = 0;

    if(sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_DB) == SQLITE_OK){

        char sSQL [BUFFER_SIZE] = "\0";
        sprintf(sSQL, "INSERT INTO livedata (device,datatype,timestamp,rawdata)");

        sqlite3_prepare_v2(_DB, sSQL, BUFFER_SIZE, &statement, &tail);
        sqlite3_exec(_DB, "BEGIN TRANSACTION", NULL, NULL, &sErrMsg);

        for (NSObject* data in dataToCache)
        {
            //NSLog(@"%@",data);

            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [[data valueForKey:@"device"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [[data valueForKey:@"type"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, [[data valueForKey:@"timestamp"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

            NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[data valueForKey:@"data"]  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 4, [str UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

            sqlite3_step(statement);
            sqlite3_clear_bindings(statement);
            sqlite3_reset(statement);
        }

        sqlite3_exec(_DB, "END TRANSACTION", NULL, NULL, &sErrMsg);
        NSLog(@"SQLiteClass - bulkCachetoSQLite - EorrorA is %s", sErrMsg);
    }
    else{
        //db isn't open
    }
    NSLog(@"SQLiteClass - bulkCachetoSQLite - EorrorB is %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_DB));
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(_DB);
}
```

Everything appears okay ERRORS return Null, but nothing is being written it to the SQLite db.

The db table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE `livedata` (
    `ID`    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `device`    TEXT,
    `datatype`  TEXT,
    `timestamp` TEXT,
    `rawdata`   TEXT
);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How do you know there are no errors if you don't check?  What's the return code from `sqlite_step`?

Comment: And what is `ERRORS`?   I don't see that anywhere in your code.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: You should only call `sqlite3_close` if `sqlite3_open` succeeds. You should only call `sqlite3_finalize` if `sqlite3_prepare_v2` succeeds. You need a lot more error checking. And use `sqlite3_errmsg` to log errors at the point of failure, not just as a catch-all at the end.

Comment: Hi, so I added a bunch of error checking and received the following error after the 'sqlite3_prepare_v2':

Database returned error 1: near ")": syntax error

Comment: Look at the syntax for `INSERT` statements at http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html

Comment: Thanks rmaddy - syntax error in SQLIte Statement - Corrected statement:

    sprintf(sSQL, "INSERT INTO livedata VALUES (NULL,@device,@datatype,@timestamp,@rawdata)");

Comment: That's not the correct statement. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides needing to add a lot more error checking, your `INSERT` is incorrect. You want:

```
char *sSQL = "INSERT INTO livedata (device,datatype,timestamp,rawdata) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
```

Comment: Both version worked (my knowledge of SQLite is rough)

    "INSERT INTO livedata VALUES (NULL,@device,@datatype,@timestamp,@rawdata)"